# Открытие сайта через IP в AWS

Tags: ip, amazon-web-services

Когда пытаюсь перейти по IP своего инстанса он не хочет открывать сайт, просто бесконечно думает, что сделать нужно чтобы он по IP открывал его?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: security groups проверяли? возможно у вас не открыт доступ к инстансу

Comment: @Exploding Kitten нет, извиняюсь, новичок в AWS, не могли бы вы описать куда конкретно нужно зайти чтобы это проверить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим у вас есть `ec2` инстанс (не важно как созданный руками, через `Elastic Beanstalk` или `CloudFormation`), но будет создан внутри некого `VPC` (виртуальная сеть для вашего аккаунта внутри `AWS`, у аккаунта есть дефолтный `VPC`), также при создании указывается `Security Group` (это файрвол, который работает до вашего инстанса и пропускает/блокирует трафик).

Предположим вы создали `ec2` инстанс, по принципу далее-далее-далее, то для него будет создана новая `Security Group`, которая будет разрешать только `SSH` (порт 22) трафик, но не `HTTP`. Например, на инстанс был установлен `Apache`. Тогда при заходе на сервер у вас ничего работать не будет, а соединение потом отвалится по таймауту.

Чтобы это исправить нужно открыть `EC2` -> `Instances` и выбрать ваш инстанс. Потом перейти во вкладку `Security` и там выбрать `Security Group`, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого откроется настройка нужной группы, в ней вам нужно проверить, чтобы существовал `Inbound Rule` для `HTTPS` трафика, если его нет добавить нажав `Edit inbound rules`. Далее `Add`, `Type` - `HTTP`, `Source` - `0.0.0.0/0` если хотите чтобы сайт был доступен с любого адреса (любого компьютера) или можете ограничить, какие `IP` адреса будут иметь доступ, например, `12.34.56.78/32`. В итоге у вас будет это выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, если проблема была в `Security Group`, то вы сможете зайти на страницу, которая хостится `Apache`.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, все работает, единственное, что стоит учитывать - это тупой маленький пунктик, что когда ты вроде бы все настроил, переходишь по IP по кнопке IP, которая находится в самом инстансе, то она перекидывает на HTTPS:IP, а не на HTTP:IP из-за чего создается впечатление, что ничего не работает, убрать букву S в HTTPS и все начинает работать, ну либо просто скопировать и вставить IP ручками, мне кажется именно это меня и сбивало с толку, когда я настраивал.